# How to launch a program from NERDtree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Whenever I try to launch a program from NERDtree it opens it for editing. What if I want to run the program instead? How can that be done?

Answer (score 3):

Put cursor on executable file, press `m` to show menu, and press `!` to launch.

You can also create own mappings for NERDtree, see example by: `:h NERDTreeAddKeyMap`